# how do I add items to a Tuple with a forEach loop?

Tags: c#, tuples

```
private List<(string cityName, string stateName)> cityAndState = new List<(string cityName, string stateName)>
{
    ("Newark", "NJ")
};
```

In my method, I am trying this but Visual Studio says that i have an error with the `Add` method

```
            var zipLookup = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Models.ZipLookup>(zipresultStr);
            
            foreach(var item in zipLookup.places)
            {
                cityAndState.Add(item.city, item.stateabbr);
            }
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need more parens to actually create the value tuple (not call a non-existent overload of `Add` with 2 strings):

```
cityAndState.Add((item.city, item.stateabbr));
```